JS Toast Notification Function - "element.classList is undefined" Error
I'm implementing a toast notification function in JavaScript. The code is very simple, so it's self-explanatory:
HTML
<div id="notifications"></div>

JS
const notify = (type, text, autohide = true) => {
  const box = `<div class="notification ${type}">${text}<span onclick="notifyHide(parentNode)"></span></div>`;
  notifications.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", box);
  if (autohide) setTimeout(() => {
    notifyHide(box);
  }, 5000);
};

const notifyHide = el => {
  el.classList.add("hide");
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.remove();
  }, 500);
};

THE ISSUE
When "autohide" is false, there's no problem: clicking on "X", the div element disappears (thanks to the added class "hide"), then is removed from the DOM.
Instead, when "autohide" is true, I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: el.classList is undefined".
What's the reason of that error?


const notify = (type, text, autohide = true) => {
  const box = `<div class="notification ${type}">${text}<span onclick="notifyHide(parentNode)"></span></div>`;
  notifications.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", box);
  if (autohide) setTimeout(() => {
    notifyHide(box);
  }, 5000);
};

const notifyHide = el => {
  el.classList.add("hide");
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.remove();
  }, 500);
};

notify("success", "This works", false);
notify("error", "This doesn't work");
#notifications {
  bottom: 20px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}

.notification {
  align-items: center;
  animation: grow 0.5s ease-in forwards;
  background-color: var(--bc);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 18px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.notification span {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABEAAAARCAYAAAA7bUf6AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAABCklEQVQ4jYWTsYrDMBBEtzLG1XEYE/L/jbkqGJMimFRHOFKFVPmKI1w/L0WsnCxp4wUVlpan8c7IzMyATtIJ6CVV9qaACuiBb6ANmx1w5b8GoHYANTBGvVegNeCHvEZJC5CkGtgXek8231yqMSiaFZQAADsDGmCSRGGNkj4k7cMeEJ8fXoqBRtLRAf3G3xFkAhpL/rkBPFAKmSQtAdH0X4rCjYl8gFxBWpJaSXdniHfg8y1gxYXMtZKCOnZhZWU5WgP8rYJ4voXRkT5J6oCjcz5Iqgz48gDBBZ6B9EC9SToXpGY5YLYfSHvPBmyAW5SJA04OSJ4IcAM2YbBb4ALsXPuWoEHSBdiamT0AyQw4IRLJeTkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 17px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 17px;
}

.notification.success {
  --bc: #55B559;
}

.notification.error {
  --bc: #EA4333;
}

.notification.hide {
  animation: shrink 0.3s ease-out forwards;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
<div id="notifications"></div>




Your box is a string, not a DOM element.

I know that. But it's always a string, even when "autohide" is false.

@AbsoluteBeginner You once call notifyHide(parentNode) and once call notifyHide(box). Only the second one fails

You add the string as a new element "afterbegin", so you could try notifyHide(notifications.firstChild) instead of notifyHide(box)

@Ivar It doesn't work if there's more than one box having "autohide" = true;

@Bergi How would you fix it?

@AbsoluteBeginner Ah right, because the firstChild is read after the timeout, by which time other elements are added. Store the notifications.firstChild in a variable before the setTimeout() and then pass that variable to the notifyHide() function.

@AbsoluteBeginner I'd probably avoid insertAdjacentHTML and rather use document.createElement and appendChild to construct the element, which you can then pass into notifyHide. Or do what Ivar recommended.

In the notify function, you define the box as a string of HTML:
const box = `<div class="notification ${type}">${text}<span onclick="notifyHide(parentNode)"></span></div>`;

However, a string is not the same as an HTML Element
Instead of passing the string box to notifyHide, you need to pass the actual DOM element that was created. Here’s how you can fix it:

Create the element from the HTML string.
Pass that element to notifyHide.

Here’s the updated code:
const notify = (type, text, autohide = true) => {
  // Create a temporary container to generate an element from the HTML string
  const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tempDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="notification ${type}">${text}<span onclick="notifyHide(parentNode)"></span></div>`;

  // Extract the actual element from the temporary container
  const notificationElement = tempDiv.firstChild;

  // Add the notification element to the DOM
  notifications.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", notificationElement);

  // Handle autohide if enabled
  if (autohide) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      notifyHide(notificationElement);
    }, 5000);
  }
};

const notifyHide = el => {
  el.classList.add("hide");
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.remove();
  }, 500);
};

Explanation:

We create a temporary div element (tempDiv) and set its innerHTML to the notification HTML string.
The firstChild of tempDiv is the actual notification element that was created.
The notificationElement is a reference to the actual DOM element, so it can be passed safely to notifyHide.

